# Swift 4 - Private method inside extension

Tags: swift, methods, private

I'm looking for a way to write a private function inside an extension.

For example:

```
class A: UIViewController {
    override viewDidLoad() {
        privateFoo()
    }
}

private extension A {
    func foo() { 
        privateFoo()
    }

    private func privateFoo() { //Helper function for foo(), expected to be called inside the scope of this extension only

    }
}
```

However, even if I declare privateFoo() as `private`, I can still call it from outside of the extension, which is not what I expected it to be.

Can you someone please help me how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Show an example of where you can unexpectedly call `privateFoo()`. Any attempt I make results in an error as expected.

Comment: Do you call `privateFoo` in other extensions of `A` defined in the same file? If so then it works as intented: "Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and **to extensions** of that declaration that are in the same file". Source: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: Here's a screenshot I made in Playground http://prntscr.com/mx40ab. As you can see privateFoo() is declared inside a private extension, yet I can still call it inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: @NShiny oh I see. I was believing that any `private` stuff declared inside a scope (in my case the extension) will not be exposed to the outside. Looks like my knowledge is obsolete

Comment: @hoangCap [Edit] your question showing your actual code causing the issue. Don't show screenshots in a comment.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use `fileprivate` if you are expanding class `A`, store the extension in the same file of `A`.  
If you are expanding class `UIViewController` you should use `public` or `internal` (default).  
If you want a really private method of `A`, put it inside class `A` instead of `extension A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to reply.

I think you can put your `private extension` in other file, it will do the trick.

---

**For example:**

FileA.swift

```
class A {
}
```

FileB.swift

```
private extension A {
    func foo() { 
        privateFoo()
    }

    func privateFoo() { 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But there will be a case, foo can be accessed only in the file "FileB.swift". function privateFoo can be accessed only and only in the same private extension.